# Issue in connecting to SOAP service from IBM JRE 1.6

Tags: ssl

Getting error SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 64; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 64]"/> while connecting to a SOAP service

I am trying to connect to a SOAP service hosted in java 1.8 tomcat environment from IBM OMS system.

Answer (score 1):

This is the main error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Array index out of range: 64'
```

The IBM JCE can throw this error if you are trying to handshake with TLS v1 on 2048 DH algorithm. 2048 DH key can be used only if you are handshaking with TLS 1.2 . Java 8 by default uses TLS v1.2

The error is because of the incompatibility between Key length (2048) and SSL handshake algorithm chosen (DHE).

IBM supports recommends three way to resolve this problem.

- Upgrade the java to 8
- Ask your destination to use DHE 1024 length and NOT DHE 2048.
- Ask your destination to disable all the Diffie Hellman Ephemeral ciphers (DHE)